# Image of an annulus of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

If we consider $f(z) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$, how do we compute $f(D^*(0,r))$, where $D^*(0,r) = \{z\in\Bbb C : 0<|z|<r\}$?

We know that $f$ has an essential singularity in 0, so by Cassorati-Weierstrass' theorem we know that the image of any perfored neighbourhood of 0 is dense in $\Bbb C$. Does this mean that $f(D^*(0,r)) = \Bbb C$?

If this is not important, how should I approach this problem instead?

Comment: Assorted suggestions: Which complex numbers have the form $1/z^2$ for $0<|z|<r$? What happens when we exponentiate this set? (For that, consider the "obvious" fundamental domains of $\exp$, the horizontal strips of height $2\pi$.) Can we see immediately whether or not the image is all of $\mathbf{C}$?

Comment: Are you allowed to apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem ?

Comment: @MartinR I haven't studied that theorem, so I don't think so. But thanks for the idea!

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I'm trying to process the suggestions, could this first set of numbers be $\{z\in \Bbb C : 0<|z| < \frac{1}{r^2}\}$? After that, I don't know how to continue from your hints.

Comment: It may help to note we can compute with specific numbers, and that properties of complex arithmetic generalize properties of real arithmetic. (So, if $z = 1/10$, what is $1/z^2$, and is that consistent with expectation?) I should maybe have asked: Do you feel clear on how the exponential map works geometrically?

Comment: Ok. Geometrically, applying $z^2$ we would get $D^*(0,r^2)$, with $\frac{1}{z^2}$ it turns into $\{z\in\Bbb C : |z|>r^2\}$. I know that the exponential turns "a square" into "a circle". Although I found this website (https://www.pacifict.com/Exponential.html) and found that the fifth to last image shows what might interest us. Is this good?

Comment: What I'd recommend is noting that $\exp$ maps each horizontal strip of height $2\pi$ onto its total image (because $\exp$ is $2\pi i$-periodic); then show the complement of a disk contains such a strip.

Comment: Of course! In order to show it, we must only take a strip form $r^2i$ to $(r^2+2\pi)i$ $\left(\{z\in\Bbb C : r^2i < z < (r^2+2\pi)i\}\right)$ and apply your comment on the periodicity, right? I took this since the complement of the disc is the last set on my previous comment.

Comment: That looks good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm putting the discussion in the comments into an answer in order to have it more clean and mark the question as answered.

Consider first $D_1 = D^*(0,r) = \{z\in\Bbb C : 0<|z|<r\}$ and $f_1(z) = z^2$, and we evaluate $f(D_1) = D^*(0,r^2) = \{z\in\Bbb C : 0<|z|<r^2\}=:D_2$. Now we take $f_2(z) = \frac{1}{f_1(z)} = \frac{1}{z^2}$, and get $f_2(D_2) = \Bbb C\setminus D(0,r^2) = \{z\in\Bbb C : |z|>r^2\}=:D_3$.

Since $\exp$ is $2\pi i$-periodic, it maps each horizontal strip of height $2\pi$ onto its total image. We only need to check that $D_3$ contains a horizontal strip of height $2\pi$, but this is simple (take for example $S = \{z\in\Bbb C : 2r^2< \Im(z)<2r^2+2\pi\}$, which is the horizontal strip of height $2\pi$ and starts at $2r^2$, in order to contain it in $D_3$).

Therefore, $f(D_1) = \Bbb C$.

This could further be revised with the Cassorati-Weierstrass theorem, since $\exp\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. Therefore, the image of $D^*(0,r)$ (a perfored neighbourhood of $0$) is dense.

I want to express my thanks to Andrew D. Hwang for assisting me in this problem. Sorry if I felt annoying!